# Extracting specific nmap output in bash

Tags: bash, port, nmap

I'm getting following nmap output from a scan:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
113/tcp  closed ident
443/tcp  open   https
5060/tcp open   sip
```

I want to extract only open ports and save them into a variable while my script progress is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Please enter your IP/domain address for nmap vulnerability scanning:
read IP
echo Your results against $ip will be output in sometime
nmap -sS -oG output.txt $ip
```

Comment: You can use --open to only show open ports

Answer (score 3):

Grep them

```
nmap -sS -oG output.txt $ip | grep open
```

To store in var

```
open_ports=$(nmap -sS -oG output.txt $ip | grep open)
open_ports=${open_ports//[^0-9]/ } # remove text
```

Convert to an array

```
open_ports_arr=( $open_ports )
```

Comment: It is good except for your array variable, it is not how you fill an array.

Comment: @LéaGris how should  I?

Comment: `mapfile -t arrayname < <(command)` or `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a arrayname < <(command)` (see my answer)

Comment: Oh, yes `readarray` is certainly the right tool for creating arrays. I just like to keep it simple)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can filter and extract open ports using awk and read the results into a bash array:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Read prompt ip address
read \
  -p 'Please enter your IP/domain address for nmap vulnerability scanning: ' \
  -r ip

# Print format info to user
printf 'Your results against %s will be output in sometime.\n' "$ip"

# Read the output of the nmap | awk commands into the ports array
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a ports < <(
  # Pipe the result of nmap to awk for processing
  nmap -sS -oG output.txt "$ip" |
    awk -F'/' '
      /[[:space:]]+open[[:space:]]+/{
        p[$1]++
      }
      END{
      for (k in p)
        print k
    }'
)

# If the resulting pors array is not empty iterate print format its content
if [ ${#ports[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
  printf 'List of open ports on host IP: %s\n' "$ip"
  for p in "${ports[@]}"; do
    printf '%d\n' "$p"
  done
fi
```

Comment: Why not just `nmap -sS -oG output.txt "$ip" | awk -F'/' '/open/{print $1}'`?

Comment: You can also use --open natively within nmap to show only open ports